# Select all or single objects from collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, select

I have an app that sends "pages" via actionmailer.  In my view code I have it setup to select a particular unit which then has medics assigned who get the email/page.  I want to include an option to page all units in my select statement but am not sure how to do it.

view/form code:

```
<%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :message %>
  <%= f.text_field :message %>

  <%= f.label 'Medic'%>

  <%= f.collection_select(:unit_id, Unit.order("unit_name ASC"), :id, :unit_name, {}, {:class => 'select'})%>

<%= f.button :send, :class => 'btn btn-info' %>

<% end %>
```

controller code:

```
def create

    @page = Paging.new(params[:paging])
    unit = Unit.find(params[:paging][:unit_id])
    message = params[:paging][:message]


     if @page.save
       PagingsMailer.paging(unit.incharge, unit, message).deliver
       PagingsMailer.paging(unit.attendant, unit, message).deliver
       redirect_to pagings_path, notice: "Page was successfully sent."
      else
        redirect_to pagings_path
     end
  end
```

The option can be in the select itself or as another select/checkbox so long as the original select is ignored.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help on this and was able to resolve it by creating an array of arrays in the form and passing "all" to the controller to perform the individual mailings.

view code:

```
<%= f.select :unit_id, options_for_select(Unit.order.map{ |unit| [unit.unit_name, unit.id] } + [["All Medics", "all"]]), {}, {:class => 'select'} %>
```

controller code:

```
def create
    message = params[:paging][:message]

    if params[:paging][:unit_id] == "all"
      Unit.all.each do |unit|
        @page = Paging.new(params[:paging])
        @page.unit_id = unit.id

        if @page.save
          PagingsMailer.paging(unit.incharge, unit, message).deliver
          PagingsMailer.paging(unit.attendant, unit, message).deliver
          flash.notice = "Page was successfully sent."
        end
      end
    else
      @page = Paging.new(params[:paging])
      unit = Unit.find(params[:paging][:unit_id])

      if @page.save
        PagingsMailer.paging(unit.incharge, unit, message).deliver
        PagingsMailer.paging(unit.attendant, unit, message).deliver
        flash.notice = "Page was successfully sent."
      end
    end
```